# Android Sqlite remove oldest duplicate results based on date column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an Android Sqlite database and I'm trying to select the top 1000 rows by RANK number, because RANK is always changing I sometimes get duplicate rows with the same RANK number, what I would like to do is only keep the duplicate row containing the newest RANK based on its CREATED_DATE, I will visually display this below:

```
id rank created_date
1  1    1/1/2014
2  2    1/1/2021
3  3    1/1/2021
4  1    1/1/2021
```

The output I want is:

```
id rank created_date
2  2    1/1/2021
3  3    1/1/2021
4  1    1/1/2021
```

My current code gets close but doesn't remove duplicate RANK based on CREATED_DATE instead it removes them based on ID which I don't want and I haven't been able to find a way to do it by CREATED_DATE

```
    Cursor c = theDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, RANK + " BETWEEN 1 AND 1000", null,
            RANK, null, ID + " ASC");
```

This code above is removing duplicates based on ID which I don't want and gives this output below:

```
id rank created_date
1  1    1/1/2014
2  2    1/1/2021
3  3    1/1/2021
```

Any help will go a long way thanks

Comment: Change the format of the dates you store in the table to YYYY-MM-DD so that it is comparable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GROUP BY` with `max()` function.

e.g. `select * from table group by rank having max(created_date)`

Comment: This solved my problem thank you!